# Questions closed with tied migration votes do not get migrated automatically

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, migration, vote-to-close

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1321963/a-easy-to-use-document-management-system-closed) was just closed with 2 votes for SuperUser and 2 votes for ServerFault and one other. It was not migrated by default.

I've flagged it for moderator attention.

Is this a bug, or is it expected to be low frequency enough for human intervention to be the best solution? Would auto-flagging be appropriate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep the systems coupled, only, in the case of a tie, flag the post for a moderator to decide where it belongs.

That way, it will get where it belongs.

The way I see it is, If the community can't decide where a question belongs, it is the moderator's job to go in and tell the community where the questions belong.

That is why we have mods, to take care of things that the community can't/doesn't.

Comment: I personally think that there should be NO automated flags - that the presence of such a flag is evidence that the system is broken.

Comment: How is that evidence that the system is broken?

Comment: See my edit for my view of it.

Comment: @jjnguy: The thing is, the community *can* resolve issues like this, the problem is that the system doesn't provide a mechanism to do so. Raising an automated flag is an easy fix, but it certainly won't scale if any more than a handful of events will trigger one.

Comment: Well, if it isn't clear to the community where a question belongs, then I believe someone of higher power should decide.

Answer (score 0):

Human intervention would be the best approach. How would the system know where it really belongs if there is a tie?

Answer (score 0):

How do you suggest breaking the tie? Should one site be preferred over the other? Or should reputation or other factors come into play?

I think the best solution would be to decouple the closing and migration systems, and require N migration votes (say, 5 or so) for a specific site for the question to be moved. This way you have to have N people not only agree that the question should be closed and/or moved, but at least N have to agree on the destination. An added side effect of decoupling the systems would be the capability of moving closed questions, something that can only effectively be done with a moderator flag.

A less desirable (but more easily implemented) solution would be to wait for a tie-breaking close vote if there's a 2-2-1 or 1-1-1-1-1 tie. The question would stay open slightly longer, but this would solve the tie-breaking problem without introducing any major new features.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the full implications of this suggestions. Does this imply two rounds of voting to migrate questions? If so, are we worried that there will be a period--after closing and before migration--when the OP can't get help with the question on *any* site? Would that encourage the OP to re-ask on another site, possibly leading to duplicates?

Comment: I don't think it would be necessary to close the question before voting to migrate it - the two can be done in parallel, but I would rather see people cast migration votes *instead of* a close vote, not *in addition to* one.

Comment: A tie breaker could work...but what if no one casts a 'belongs on' vote?  Or, what if it gets moved to the wrong site?

Comment: I like it. Only, I can't help envisioning 2 each for SU and SF and 1 for, say, S&A. Followed by 2 for NPR, then another S&A, then...without ever breaking tie

Comment: @dmckee: Such an occurrence would be possible, but very unlikely in practice (much less likely than a simple 2-2-1 tie). And ultimately it can't go on forever because there will be a point where every option is at 2, causing the next vote to be the deciding vote.